# How to find common patterns in thousands of strings?

Tags: substring, data-analysis

I don't want to find "abc" in strings ["kkkabczzz", "shdirabckai"]

Not like that.

But bigger patterns like this:

If I have to __, then I will ___.

["If I have to do it, then I will do it right.", "Even if I have to make it, I will not make it without Jack.", "....If I have to do, I will not...."]

I want to discover patterns in a large array or database of strings. Say going over the contents of an entire book.

Is there a way to find patterns like this?

I can work with JavaScript, Python, PHP.

Comment: These patterns in the strings are [phrasal templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_template). Each template contains one or more collocations, so I would use a [collocation extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_extraction) algorithm to search for common templates.

Comment: crosspost at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111739/how-to-find-common-patterns-in-thousands-of-strings

Answer (score 1):

The following could be a starting point:

The RegExp `rx=/(\b\w+(\s+\w+\b)+)(?=.+\1)+/g` looks for small (multiple word) patterns that occur at least twice in the text.

By playing around with the repeat quantifier `+` after `(\s+\w+\b)` (i.e. changing it to something like `{2}`) you can restrict your word patterns to any number of words (in the above case to 3: original + 2 repetitions) and you will get different results.

`(?=.+\1)+` is a look ahead pattern that will not consume any of the matched parts of the string, so there is "more string" left for the remaining match attempts in the `while` loop.

```js
const str="If I have to do it, then I will do it right. Even if I have to make it, I will not make it without Jack. If I have to do, I will not."

const rx=/(\b\w+(\s+\w+\b)+)(?=.+\1)+/g, r={};

let t;
while (t=rx.exec(str)) r[t[1]]=(rx.lastIndex+=1-t[1].length);

const res=Object.keys(r).map(p=>
  [p,[...str.matchAll(p)].length]).sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1]||b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));
// list all repeated patterns and their occurrence counts, 
// ordered by occurrence count and alphabet: 
console.log(res);
```

I extended my snippet a little bit by collecting all the matches as keys in an object (`r`). At the end I list all the keys of this object alphabetically with `Object.keys(r).sort()`.

In the `while` loop I also reset the `rx.lastIndex` property to start the search for that next pattern immediately after the start of the last one found: `rx.lastIndex+=1-t[1].length`.